# 1999 olds alero wont acelerate over 70mph need help

Tags: maintenance, performance

I have a 1999 Oldsmobile alero 4cylinder. This is what im noticing when I put the car in drive sometimes, and press gas the car doesn't want to go it hesitate even when im pressing gas a n d then I will let it go and try again and it goes. The other problem im having when im in the highway and try to accelarate over 70mph it wont let me go any faster even when I push the pedal all the way down and the rpm just stays at 3000 the speed wont go past 70 mph please help?

Comment: This would be much easier to read if you would punctuate and capitalize the sentences, rather than running them all together.  And please proofread for spelling and clarity - it's hard to tell from this what your problem is.

Comment: Sounds like it might be the start of a plugged catalytic convertor.

Answer (score 1):

Ther are many faults that this can be caused by. A scan on your vehicles engine and transmission would be a good first step. You can try revving the engine whilst stationary and with the e/handbrake applied and the vehicle in 'Park'. If the engine will rev up into the 6000 RPM range you will know the engine is OK. If you cant achieve a high rev, you may have a speed limiter kicking in because of an engine fault, or a seized stator in your transmissions torque converter. Scans first.

Comment: Hi I did what you said I turned the car on left it in park and applied the e/brake. And the rpm will only go to 4000 range no higher what's this mean?

Comment: It can be a few faults. If your engine check light is staying on(little yellow/black picture of an engine) then you have an emissions problem and the engine ECU is restricting engine RPM to minimise harmful emissions. This is usually known as 'limp home mode' and allows the vehicle to be driven to a repair facility. The other part is in your torque convertor. It has a part in it called a stator which goes to multiply your engine power. If the stator seizes then it acts as a brake on the engine and has to be replaced. Have a scan on the vehicle , you may only have a minor emission fault.

Comment: Ok I will do that thank you and also the engine light is not on the only light that is on is the trac off and anti lock light on it comes on once I start the car and drive it maybe for about a mile.

Comment: @AllanOsborne very good follow up.  Please edit your answer with your comment for the rest of us please. +1